# variable value is two strings

Tags: php

Somehow a variable that SHOULD contain only one string (not an array or anything) contain an url, managed to contain two different values;

```
string(8) "value 1 " string(7) "value 2"
```

i cannot use this variable because echoing it or using it in another function would print

```
value 1 value2
```

which is not what i need, i need only value 1 and i cannot use $var[0]

Two things; how can i do something similar (one variable two strings), and how can i manipulate it.
EDIT : here is the code

```
public function get_first_image($post) {
        $image_id=get_post_thumbnail_id($post->id);
        $image_url = wp_get_attachment_image_src($image_id,’large’);
        $image_url=$image_url[0];
        var_dump($image_url);
        return $image_url;
    }
```

the var_dump() results are as mentioned above

Best Regards

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't reuse $image_url as a variable, this is most likely causing your problem.
You should rename one of your variables:

```
public function get_first_image($post) {
    $image_id = get_post_thumbnail_id($post->id);

    $image_array = wp_get_attachment_image_src($image_id,’large’);
    $image_url = $image_array[0];

    var_dump($image_url);
    return $image_url;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You question doesn't give a great amount of detail. If you need access to part of a string you can use the `explode()` function. So if the string contained no spaces between the separate values, you could use `$newstring = explode(" ",$oldstring); echo $newstring[0];` This would then give you access  to the first part of the string.

I'd recommend you look up [string concatenation](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.string.php).

If you can give us further details, we may be able to assist you further.